# Optional generic definition in class

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I would like to make the definition of the generic type optional; I mean, I have the following.

```
export class ApiResponse<T>{
    message:string;
    data:T;
    codResult:ResponseType;
}

export class ApiResponse{
    message:string;
    codResult:ResponseType;
}
```

I don't want to have to define a type at all even though I don't require the "data" property. In C # I have, in fact I usually make the guy who receives data inherit from the guy who doesn't. But I see that in typescript it doesn't allow to have both classes clearly because they have the same name.
In summary, I want to have the ApiResponse class but to which if I specify the generic type it has the data property, otherwise not.

I would like to apply something like the following.

```
class ApiResponse{
    message:string;
    codResult:ResponseType;
}
class ApiResponse<T> extends ApiResponse {
    data: T;
}
```

Comment: Why exactly can't you use inheritance? `class ApiResponse{message:string;codResult:ResponseType;}` and `class ApiPayloadResponse<T> extends ApiResponse {data: T;}`

Comment: It's just a matter of wanting to use the same name. For example in c # I have this `public enum ResponseType
    {
        Success = 1,
        Alert = 2,
        Error = 3
    }
    public class ResponseDto
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public ResponseType ResponseType { get; set; } = ResponseType.Alert;
    }
    public class ResponseDto<Type> : ResponseDto
    {
        public Type Data { get; set; }
    }`